First 10 characters from a column in a query
How can I read only the first 10 characters from a column in a query?
In column B of a table there are date values (e.g. 30.04.2022 - 30.04.2022)
from which I only want to read the first 10 characters (first date), so 30.04.2022 = 10 characters.
=query(VA!$A2:$AA;"Select B,AA where Y Contains 'YES' Order By B desc ")

that results:

       COLUMN B         COLUMN AA

30.04.2022 - 30.04.2022  |    848,41 €
28.05.2022 - 29.05.2022  |  3.733,64 €
27.08.2022 - 27.08.2022  |  1.303,74 €
27.07.2024 - 27.07.2024  |  1.173,83 €
26.08.2023 - 26.08.2023  |  1.301,40 €


I want this:

 COLUMN B      COLUMN AA

30.04.2022  |    848,41 €
28.05.2022  |  3.733,64 €
27.08.2022  |  1.303,74 €
27.07.2024  |  1.173,83 €
26.08.2023  |  1.301,40 €

How do I have to adapt the query query?

Try this out:
=LET(q;QUERY(VA!A2:AA;"Select B,AA where Y Contains 'YES' Order By B desc ");
     {INDEX(LEFT(q;10);;1)\INDEX(q;;2)})


Thank you for your help, but column AA with the formula slides under column B.
What do I have to add?
30.04.2022  
28.05.2022    
27.08.2022    
27.07.2024    
26.08.2023    
848,41 €
3.733,64 €
1.303,74 €
1.173,83 €
1.301,40 €


please share a sample sheet where you demonstrate the issue.

I noticed your locale expects ; instead of ,. Try the updated formula.

Here is the sheet...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OdnjeYRJW7pt-rghcrP0xGQpSsD8j50ujVH5E2l0yYE/edit?usp=sharing

May I seek your help again?
Is it possible to design the formula so that the query narrows down a date range (column B)? The start date would be in F4 and the end date would be in G4
See my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OdnjeYRJW7pt-rghcrP0xGQpSsD8j50ujVH5E2l0yYE/edit?usp=sharing

please create a new question.
